# AngularJS: find the index position of filtered value in the original array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
$scope.data = [
    {
    "name": "Jim",
    "id" : 25
    },
    {
    "name": "Jerry",
    "id": 27
    },
    {
    "name": "Rithika",
    "id": 20
    }
    ];

    <div ng-repeat="person in data | filter: {id:20}">
        {{parent_index}}
    </div>
```

parent_index - Index of the filtered element in the actual array.

In this example, parent_index should return 2. how to find it?

Comment: Have you tried `$index`, iterator offset of the repeated element

Comment: please, provide more info about your question, its not clear and missed some data: what is `parent_index`, `var data` is out of scope and sure `ng-repeat` doesn't work

Comment: $index is returning zero. because filtered array has only one value [{"name" : "Rithika", "id" : 20 }]

Comment: @MaximShoustin question updated. let me know if it is not clear

Answer (score 81, accepted):

> find the index position of filtered value in the original array

Try this one:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in data | filter: {id:20}">
    {{data.indexOf(person)}}
</div>
```

Output: `2`

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/902/)**</kbd>

Comment: If you happen to be searching in a controller or service using `$filter('filter')`, then it returns an array of matches, so you can't just pass the result directly to `indexOf`.  It my case I was filtering over a unique key, so I could safely do something like `index = data.indexOf(person[0])`

Comment: Hah! Thanks for the comment Parris Varney from December 9th - Parris Varney from May 9th was stuck on this same issue.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a little helper function for finding index of an object in the array on given property value:

```
function getIndexOf(arr, val, prop) {
      var l = arr.length,
        k = 0;
      for (k = 0; k < l; k = k + 1) {
        if (arr[k][prop] === val) {
          return k;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
```

example:

```
var arrOfobj = [
       {a:1, b:1, c:1}, //index 0
       {a:2, b:2, c:2}, //index 1
       {a:3, b:3, c:3} //index 2
    ];
var index = getIndexOf(arrOfobj, "2", "a");
```

Script above would result in index = 1 because property "a" has value 2 in second object in the array.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `$index` value for loops.

```
<div ng-repeat="person in data | filter: {id:20}">{{$index+1}}<div>
```

Comment: This won't give you the index value in the original array only the filtered array.