# Number the rows in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table which has a `ng-repeat` directive in it. It uses a filter to filter out objects not having property qty>0. I need to give a serial no. to each of the rows. Note that the rows are not fixed. If a user changes the qty of a product to make it 0, it is removed from the table.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
    <th>S.no</th><th>Product Name</th><th>Qty</th><th>Sub-Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="orders" ng-repeat="product in products" ng-if="product.qty">
    <td>{{$index}}</td><td>{{product.name}}</td><td> <input type="number" min="0" ng-blur="product.qty = qty" ng-model="qty" value="{{product.qty}}"> </td> <td>{{product.qty*product.price | currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, the problem with this code is that, the `$index` gives the actual index of the product in the products array. I need it to give the index in the filtered array. How do I do that?

Comment: Like I saw here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756694/angularjs-find-the-index-position-of-filtered-value-in-the-original-array
You can try this products.indexOf(product)

Comment: @Anfelipe that i can get through `$index` as well. I need numbers from 1...n for n rows which may change if user inputs 0 as qty for any product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the items beforehand as follows:

```
<tr class="orders" ng-repeat="product in filterItems(products)">
    <td>{{$index}}</td><td>{{product.name}}</td><td> <input type="number" min="0" ng-blur="product.qty = qty" ng-model="qty" value="{{product.qty}}"> </td> <td>{{product.qty*product.price | currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.filterItems = function(items) {
    var filtered_items = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        if(item.qty > 0) {
            filtered_items.push(item)
        }
    })
    return filtered_items;
}
```

Comment: Maybe also use filter function instead of a forEach: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 2):

Use filter in `ng-repeat`:

HTML

```
<tr class="orders" ng-repeat="product in products | filter: hasQty">
    <td>{{$index}}</td><td>{{product.name}}</td><td> <input type="number" min="0" ng-blur="product.qty = qty" ng-model="qty" value="{{product.qty}}"> </td> <td>{{product.qty*product.price | currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
$scope.hasQty = function (value) {
    return value.qty > 0
}
```

Untested.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I guess `ng-if` was the problem. It just hid the elements.