# How to get the array index using AngularJS filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get this filter:

```
userInfo = $filter('filter')(userArray, {userId: userId});
```

and got the userInfo object. Is there anyway that I can find out which array index of userArray.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: find the index position of filtered value in the original array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756694/angularjs-find-the-index-position-of-filtered-value-in-the-original-array)

Answer (score 0):

Following the docs, you can see that you can use a function instead of the object {userId: userId}. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter#filter-arguments

Right now your code should be equivalent to the following:

```
userInfo = $filter('filter')(userArray, function(element, index) {
    if (element.userId == userId) return true;
});
```

Note that the function added to the filter contains the index that you need.

You may change the function to make use of that index, but bear in mind that you must return true only for the elements that you want to pass the filter.

Comment: You are welcome! But don't forget to mark my answer as correct! :-)

Comment: Sorry, Another question. I really want to return the index because I need to use this index to update the data outside of this function(function(element, index) lll